# Why using # in latex in \mintinline{}{} returns an error?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

Latex returns error when I write # in \mintinline

When i delete # problem disappears.

```latex
\section{Example 1 - \mintinline{bash}{${#parameter}}}
```

Can somebody help?

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZuJe.png)

Code listing:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{minted} 

\begin{document}

\section{Example 1 - \mintinline{bash}{${#parameter}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre]? The problem is probably that you have fragile content as argument of the section macro. It might help if you give an alternative short title without fragile content such as code listings.

Comment: I added code listing, same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little help from the `cprotect` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{cprotect}

\begin{document}

\cprotect\section[Example 1]{Example 1 - \mintinline{bash}|${#parameter}|  }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Both `$` and `#` are special characters in LaTeX: `$` opens and closes ‘maths mode’, and `#` refers to a numbered parameter of a function.

If you need to refer to them as ordinary characters, you need to escape them with `\$` and `\#` respectively (to be pedantic, `\$` isn't ‘escaping’ as such, but instead a command `\$` which expands to `$` as an ordinary character).

That's presuming that `\mintinline` doesn't do something clever to make special characters non-special (some macros do so, for convenience).  Presuming not, and recalling that `{` and `}` are special characters to, I *guess* that you can get what you want with

```
\mintinline{bash}{\$\{\#parameter\}}}
```

(which is unfortunately a bit of a mess to type...).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Output in pdf is : "Example 1 - \$\{\#parameter\}"

Comment: “That's presuming that `\mintinline` doesn't do something clever to make special characters non-special” — Yet that’s precisely what’s happening here (`\mintinline` is like `\verb`). And this *works* — just not when nested inside other macro arguments. Packages such as ‘cprotect’ work around this limitation.